# Browse Menu at a lot of Subsites

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to realize the following in TYPO3 7.6 LTS means fluid and Typoscript.

This site structure exists:
author
    book 1
        page 1
        Page 2
        Setie 3
        ...
    book 2
        page 1
        Page 2
        page 3
       ...

Defines a standard Excessive Typoscript menu is additionally browse the type that the possibilities First page / Previous / book / Next / Last page appear on page 1, etc. to display. Since there is at this point a number of trees that are to be equipped with a menu that is likely a Condition unde the regular expansion in Typoscript by the editor representing not optio times solution.

How can I implement means Typoscript and board means the most? Previously I had the whole by means of EXT: cagpagebrowser realized, this will not be further developed and, unfortunately, a revision of the same is not possible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a common root page to group the author pages and their subpages into one branch of the tree. Then you could use the condition

```
PIDupinRootline
```

to activate the menu just for subpages within this particular branch of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

as there is a HMENU.special = [browse](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#hmenu-special-property) you could do most of the extension cagpagebrowser also with the build in tools of TYPO3.

if you want the browse menu on different levels like:
author: first, previous, next, last
book: first, previous, author index (up), next, last
chapter: first, previous, book index (up), next, last
page: first, previous, chapter index (up), next, last
you might combine a rootline menu with the browse menu